# Is the R function for dividing dual y(mutiple) in time-series graph?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to plot graph that dual y according to concentration(ppm, temperature etc.)

Reference data is here.

[image]

Using this data, i want to make graph below.

[image]

In terms of dividing physical unit like "concentration, Celsius", i moved "Gas.temp" to right y axis.
I used library 'ggplot', 'openair', but couldn't find any related function what i want plot because lack of knowledge.

In summary, point is, how to move "Gas.temp" to right y axis in the multiple time-series graph in R.

Thank you so much..!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `geom_ts()` from `FOQAT` package is an easy way. Please try this exmaple:

```
library(foqat)
head(aqi)
geom_ts(
  df=aqi,   
  yl=4, yr=6,   
  llist=c(4, 6),   
  yllab=bquote(NO[2]~" "~(ppbv)), yrlab=bquote(O[3]~" "~(ppbv)), xlab="Datetime",  
  llab=list(bquote(NO[2]~" "), bquote(O[3]~" ")),  
  lcc=c("#096dd9","#ff4d4f"),
  ana=FALSE
)

#                Time        NO     NO2       CO SO2      O3
#1 2017-05-01 01:00:00 0.0376578 2.79326 0.256900  NA 56.5088
#2 2017-05-01 01:01:00 0.0341483 2.76094 0.254692  NA 57.0546
#3 2017-05-01 01:02:00 0.0310285 2.65239 0.265178  NA 57.6654
#4 2017-05-01 01:03:00 0.0357016 2.60257 0.269691  NA 58.7863
#5 2017-05-01 01:04:00 0.0337507 2.59527 0.273395  NA 59.0342
#6 2017-05-01 01:05:00 0.0238120 2.57260 0.276464  NA 59.2240
```

[image]